# Angular JS highlight row based on radio button state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I have a table with a set of rows, using an ng-repeat:

`<tr ng-repeat="model in modelList" ng-class="{hilite : model.select}">`

each row with a radio button like so:

`<input type="radio" name="modelGroup" ng-model="model.select">`

The radio buttons work, but I am trying to set the class of the row to highlight the background of the row with the clicked radio button.

Plunkr here:http://plnkr.co/edit/WSgC4Y4FmlzOr7Bfmlpp?p=preview

I've done this several times this way with *checkboxes* so I can't figure out what is wrong with the radio buttons.  Being in a repeater, I though every row had its own scope, so the state of the model would affect the TR, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your input a value and change the model value to point to the same model since it's a radio button and data needs to be exclusive

```
<input type="radio" name="modelGroup" ng-model="selected.value" value="{{$index}}">
```

change your ng-class to

```
ng-class="{hilite : selected.value == $index}"
```

Also make sure you create the variable in your controller and it should come under a different parent otherwise the ng-repeat will get it confused as a child of its data

```
$scope.selected = {value: null}
```

So it looks like

```
    <tr ng-repeat="model in modelList" ng-class="{hilite : selected.value == $index}">
          <td>
             <input type="radio" name="modelGroup" ng-model="selected.value" value="{{$index}}">
          </td>
         <td>{{ model.NDPName }}</td>
         <td>{{ model.OEM }}</td>
         <td>{{ model.version }}</td>
         <td>{{ model.dateAdded }}</td>
         <td>{{ model.validUntil }}</td>
     </tr>
```

I've changed ur [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/k9rGCd2WF17X6GE1yPOv?p=preview)

Comment: Cool, except the highlight doesn't go away when a radio button is un-selected.

Comment: Yeah I realised, are you sure you want radio buttons and not checkboxes? the way you have structured your data suggests you want checkboxes since each object within your array have a select that can be true or false.

Comment: No, they want radios for some reason.  They want to make it obvious the choices are mutually exclusive.  As I said, checkboxes I have done many times without issue.

Comment: then you should change your data structure, the radio boxes should point to one model instead of a model for each radio box otherwise it can't be exclusive.

Comment: But if it's one model, what would the ng-class bind to?

Comment: Very clever, thanks.  For anyone following along, here is the latest plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zuiqitff1NIdRlYrKBoD?p=preview

Comment: could use `ng-value="$index"` instead of `value="{{$index}}"` ;)